# Showing multiple images with Owl carousel outside container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I am using Owl Carousel plugin to show 4 thumbnails in a row container (with Bootstrap). How do I show more thumbnails outside the container without changing 4 thumbnails inside container? I have seen this effect on a couple of websites, sadly I don't remember exactly where.

Images outside container are like in shadow until they enter inside and become visible. In image, blue thumbnails are regular images and those outside have opacity toned down or they have background color as overlay.

[image]

```
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav: true,
    navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
    dots: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 3200,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    responsive:{
      0:{
        items:1
      },
      600:{
        items:4
      }
    }
  })


<div class="container">
      <ul class="owl-carousel">
        <li>
          <figure>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
          </figure>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyLOrq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your styles:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
    overflow: visible;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer .owl-item {
    opacity: 0.25;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer .owl-item.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Play with the values to your liking.

Comment: wow, it is that easy? I was afraid to ask thinking it is too complicated

Comment: One thing I learned from bashing my head on the desk too many times is to try to think simpler everywhere - simple is better. Try thinking in CSS first, then in JavaScript.